# How to get document fields after using $unwind on embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

I have this document with name of Products that have one embedded document that named comments:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "test",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "userId" : 3,
            "comment" : "hi",
            "verified" : false,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-09-18T21:21:02.280Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

And i use this query in php to get comments:

```
$this->mongo_db->aggregate("Products", [['$unwind' => '$comments'], ['$sort' => ['comments.date' => -1]], ['$project' => ["name" => 1, "comments" => 1]], ['$match' => ['comments.verified' => false]], ['$project' => ["comments._id" => 1, "comments.date" => 1, "comments.dateD" => ['$dateToString' => ['format' => '%Y-%m-%d', 'date' => '$comments.date']]]]]);
```

This is my result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1,
    "comments" : { 
        "_id" : 2,
        "comment" : "hi", 
        "date" : ISODate("2017-09-18T21:21:02.280Z"), 
        "dateD" : "2017-09-18"
     } 
}
```

This is the result I want using aggregation in mongodb:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1,
    "name": "test",
    "comments" : { 
        "_id" : 2,
        "comment" : "hi", 
        "date" : ISODate("2017-09-18T21:21:02.280Z"), 
        "dateD" : "2017-09-18"
     } 
}
```

Now i want to get product name, and I write **name => 1** in $project but nothing returned. and when I delete second $project pipeline it works fine.

Comment: Because you removed them with `$project` stages. If you simply remove both of those `$project` stages from the pipeline completely then the document state is basically unaltered. All `$unwind` does it makes a new copy of the document for every array member. So it's not `$unwind` changing the document, it's "you".

Comment: @NeilLunn Well after removing both $project, how can I use this **"comments.dateD" => ['$dateToString' => ['format' => '%Y-%m-%d', 'date' => '$comments.date']]**?

Comment: `$project` requires that you **explicitly** name every single property you wish to return. You only have access to data in a new pipeline stage what you emit from a previous one. So simply add `name => ` **to the same stage**. And remove the earlier `$project` because it's basically useless. Also `$dateToString` is pretty useless without `$group`. And if you intend to `$group` then you should be writing that "directly" in that stage instead. So it looks like you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: I have `name => 1` in first `$project`. Can you help me and tell me how can 
I use `$dateToString` with `$group`? I want both name and that `$dateToString` expression.

Comment: As suspected, this is wandering into asking a different question to how you presented in the first place. I suggest you instead try and show by example some data you actually have and the result you are expecting to get from the aggregation.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank for your suggestion, I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use $addFields pipeline

```
$this->mongo_db->aggregate("Products", [['$unwind' => '$comments'], ['$sort' => ['comments.date' => -1]], ['$project' => ["name" => 1, "comments" => 1]], ['$match' => ['comments.verified' => false]], ['$addFields' => ["comments.dateD" => ['$dateToString' => ['format' => '%Y-%m-%d', 'date' => '$comments.date']]]]]);
```